# Django scripts can't access files from docker volume

Tags: python, django, docker-compose

I added `data` folder (containing files with metadata) to the `.dockerignore` file. Because I don't want to weigh down my containers.  don't want my containers to be too heavy. Since the `data` folder contains huge files that need to be read by the application. So I decided to mount a volume in my docker-compose like below. And when I go inside the `web container` I can see the file. And inside the container when I type `/sigma/data/imports/dbm.csv` I get the data. But when trying to read the file I got this error:

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sigma/data/imports/dbm.csv'`

Am I missing out or misunderstood something?

- Docker compose file (an extract)

```
web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    entrypoint: /sigma/docker-entrypoint.sh
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./data:/sigma/data
```

- View that read the file

  In the `settings.py` file, I have this: `IMPORTS_PATH = '/sigma/data/imports/'`

```py
file_path = settings.IMPORTS_PATH + 'dbm.csv'
df_import = pd.read_csv(
                file_path, sep=';',
                header=0,
                usecols=cols,
                index_col=False,
                on_bad_lines='skip',
            )
```